# Переместить scroll с родительского элемента на дочерний

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify, modal

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть модальное окно и, изначально было так, что скроллбар прокручивал всю область.
[image: Изначальный вид]
Необходимо перенести его ниже. Я это сделал, но работает криво. Для всего модального окна задал значение **overflow-y: hidden**. А для дочернего элемента с классом **content** (где расположено всё, что ниже заголовка и до кнопок "OK" и "Отмена"), задал **overflow-y: auto** и **height: -webkit-fill-available**.
В результате, скролл есть, но он уходит за рамки модального окна.
[image: После внесения правок]
И, разумеется, кнопок снизу не видно.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="v-dialog pc-modal-dialog v-dialog--active" style="width: 1200px;">
  <div class="pc-dialog-card v-card v-sheet theme--light">
    <div class="v-card__title headline grey lighten-2 v-card__title--primary">Выбор изображения</div>
    <div class="v-card__text content">
      <!-- Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок -->
    </div>
    <hr class="v-divider theme--light">
    <div class="v-card__actions">
      <div data-v-66109643="" class="container d-flex align-right">
        <div data-v-66109643="" class="spacer"></div>
        <button data-v-66109643="" type="button" class="v-btn theme--light">
               <div class="v-btn__content">OK</div>
            </button>
        <button data-v-66109643="" type="button" class="v-btn theme--light">
               <div class="v-btn__content">Отмена</div>
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```css
/* visual */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.v-dialog {
  background: gray;
}

.v-card {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  width: 90%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #555;
}

.v-card__title,
.v-card__actions {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.v-card__text {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* styling */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.v-dialog {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.v-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.v-card__text {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-dialog pc-modal-dialog v-dialog--active">
  <div class="pc-dialog-card v-card v-sheet theme--light">
    <div class="v-card__title headline grey lighten-2 v-card__title--primary">Выбор изображения</div>
    <div class="v-card__text content">
      Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много
      картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления,
      много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы
      управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок
      <br>Всякие элементы управления, много-много картинок <br>
    </div>
    <hr class="v-divider theme--light">
    <div class="v-card__actions">
      <div data-v-66109643="" class="container d-flex align-right">
        <div data-v-66109643="" class="spacer"></div>
        <button data-v-66109643="" type="button" class="v-btn theme--light">
               <div class="v-btn__content">OK</div>
            </button>
        <button data-v-66109643="" type="button" class="v-btn theme--light">
               <div class="v-btn__content">Отмена</div>
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```